# What are the strategies to deal with intractable integrals encountered when solving ODE using variational method.?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system, variational-analysis

I am trying to solve a nonlinear ODE: $$u_{xx}+\tan^2(x)u+gu^2=0$$ using the variational method, and I encountered an intractable integral. What are the strategies to deal with intractable integrals in the framework of variational method?

Comment: For example … ?

Comment: Like this one $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}tan^2(z\sqrt{\alpha})exp(-\frac{z^2}{\beta})dz$